# Creating Element as first item within another element using Wxs (Windows Installer)

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I am using Wix installer for an application and one of the scenarios I am trying to handle is changes to a .config file when the application is upgraded. 
Essentially, I would want to add an Xml Element within another Xml Element.
For instance, the original .config file that was shipped with application looked like this

```
<root-element>
  <sub-element-1/>
  <sub-element-2/>
</root-element>
```

During app lifetime, it was updated to as below at some point.

```
<root-element>
  <sub-element-0/>
  <sub-element-1/>
  <sub-element-2/>
</root-element>
```

For handling this case , where I need to add `<sub-element-0/>` under `<root-element>`, I tried this Wxs code.

```
<util:XmlFile Id="MyConfig" 
   File="[fileidOfMyConfigFile]"
   Action="createElement"
   Name="sub-element-0"
   ElementPath="root-element" 
   Sequence="1"/>
```

The above formulation does add the `sub-element-0` under `root-element` , however as the *last* item under the `root-element`.
like so

```
<root-element>
  <sub-element-1/>
  <sub-element-2/>
  <sub-element-0/>
</root-element>
```

I couldn't find any resources on adding it as first element as I want it to be.
Any suggestions on how it could be accomplished?

**Note**: The above is a simplified version of my use case. The reason order is important in my case is due to a limitation on the framework that some elements need to occur before other elements in the `.config`